# Database Errors from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, editing

One of the databases I use is throwing a DBMS error when editors are editing the database through ArcMap. It says that the layer was unloaded due to memory pressure. This error doesn't occur for every editor when they are working with the versioned layers in an editing session. It seems to be an intermittent issue limited to one database when editors are adding data to feature classes.
I have no idea what that means. Can anyone help?

Comment: You probably are going to have a better chance getting your question answered by posting it on Database Administrators. As it stands at the moment, there is no GIS component in your question.

Comment: @Techie_Gus what are you talking about she is asking about using a spatial database in ArcMap. ESRI has a help article about it but it doesnt look very helpful : http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012156

Comment: @atxgis The error is *reported* by ArcGIS, but is *generated* by the database.  This question really needs an [Edit] to specify which exact database and which exact error, but the solution is pure database administration.

Comment: What database? Is it PostgreSQL,Oracle etc. Have you watched the server load constantly? if so, what is the memory usage on the server like? For what it's worth @Techie_Gus is right, although the error is occurring in ArcMap it may not be an ArcMap issue, it's more likely to be a 3rd party software problem. Esri has white papers on tuning like http://downloads.esri.com/support/documentation/sde_/1009ArcSDE_Config_GD_Oracle.pdf, have you read one of these?

Comment: @atxgis my comment referred to the first revision of the question which did not make any mention of ArcMap.